# Issue with laptop screen when opening lid

Tags: arch-linux, laptop, monitors, acpi, brightness

I use Archlinux, with acpid to configure the laptop lid behavior rather than systemd.

Currently, I have it set so vbetool sets dpms off when the lid is closed, and reopening the lid sets it back on.  However, sometimes (roughly 1 in every 10 lid openings, doesn't happen with a particular pattern), setting the dpms back on fails to work.  Once I close and reopen again, everything is fine.

Any ideas why that might be? Or how I can get more info about what's going wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I got this behavior to occur while I was on the framebuffer, and here is what it output:

```
[drm:intel_enable_transcoder] *ERROR* failed to enable transcoder 0
```

If someone has an idea on what I can do from this point, that'd be fantastic.

Comment: Well, have you tried the obvious, sleep a second and try turning it on again?

Answer (score 0):

That error was output by the kernel.  You could try upgrading the kernel to see if the problem's been fixed.